# Have powershell "read" all files in a specific folder and check for empty

Tags: powershell

I am saving on a daily basis a number of files into a specific folder (xls). Is there a way that I could have powershell gather each file into a different variable (it could be 2 files, it could be 5) and then see if there are more than 2 lines of text in each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to gather them into a variable necessarily, depending on what you wanted to do once you found the files.

Basic example:
If I have 3 text files created named Test1.txt, Test2.txt, Test3.txt. With just basic "line x" to depict the line number. Contents of one say Test1.txt is

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Test2.txt stops at "Line 2", and then Test3.txt just has "Line 1".
A one liner solution that would work in this instance, that will just output the name with greater than 2 lines:

```
dir *.txt | foreach {if ((Get-Content $_).Count -gt 2) {$_.Name}
```

Output from this code gives me Test1.txt.

In your situation you could just do the `dir` command for "*.xls" or whatever file extension you are using.

Comment: on "Count -gt 21" is that supposed to be "Count -gt 2"?

Answer (score 0):

This is an awesome piece of scripting.  I needed to add a second item which was the last line in the file as well, and this is how I got that done.  Thanks so much again!

**dir *.log | foreach {if ((Get-Content $*).Count -gt 1) {$*.Name + ",   " +(Get-Content $_)[-1]} }**